# windows 8 metro app collectionviewsource databinding issue

Tags: data-binding, gridview, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I have a collectionviewsource

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Name="groupedItemsViewSource" 
                          ItemsPath="Items" />
```

and give it as the itemssource to a gridview

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource groupedItemsViewSource}}"
```

the source is set in the code behind file:

```
groupedItemsViewSource.Source = AllGroups;
```

and AllGroups is

```
public ObservableCollection<DataGroup> AllGroups
```

where DataGroup Contains an Observable collection of items

```
 public ObservableCollection<DataItem> Items
```

the problem is that it does not display groups with items, instead I only get 3 gridviewitems, wich correspond to the 3 datagroups in AllGroups

I tried adding IsSourceGroupped = "true" but when I do that the application crashes, a window appears saying "an unhandled win32 exception occured in myapp.exe [3192]"

Answer (score 0):

The Source property in CollectionViewSource should implement the IGrouping interface, otherwise the the groups won't work in GridView or ListView.
Either use Linq expression GroupBy to group your results into groups with specified key, or you can extent the ObservableCollection class like this:

```cs
public class GroupedObservableCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T>, IGrouping<string, T>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Key as the Group identificator.
    /// </summary>
    public string Key { get; set; }
}
```

and use this in your class (I have CollectionViewSource in ViewModel, not in XAML):

```cs
public GroupedObservableCollection<DataItem> Items

groupedItemsViewSource = new CollectionViewSource { Source = AllGroups, ItemsPath = new PropertyPath("Items"), IsSourceGrouped = true };
```

This way the binding would work. Also make sure you use proper bindings in ListView and GridView:

```xml
<!-- zoomed in view -->
<GridView ItemsSource="{Binding groupedItemsViewSource.View}" ... />

<!-- zoomed out view -->
<GridView ItemsSource="{Binding groupedItemsViewSource.View.CollectionGroups}" ... />
```

Comment: I implemented the GroupedObservableCollection as you said, but again whenever I add the issourcegrouped = true the app crashes. if i remove the issourcegrouped it runs but again I only see 3 items for the 3 datagroups

Comment: Have you set different Key property in each DataGroup object? Also both AllGroups and Items are properties, not fields?

Comment: both allgroups and items are properties. Key properties are fine, but allgroups is empty at the beggining, i get data from a source, and when i add the first datagroup to AllGroups this is when it crashes if i have issourcegrouped = true. I removed it, put a breakpoint, and I see AllGroups having the data just fine, but still in the UI the binding works wrong. Also when i set the groupedItemsViewSource.View as a source to the datagrid i see nothing. if i set groupedItemsViewSource alone then i get the 3 items wrong

Answer (score 0):

It looks like all you're missing is the IsSourceGrouped="true" attribute on the CollectionViewSource.

Comment: when i add this it crashes, and i get "an unhandled win32 exception occured in myapp.exe [3192]"